# CoreData: annotation: Failed to load optimized model at path

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-data, swift4

I am trying to integrate Google Map in my iOS app which is being developed in Swift4. I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) tutorial. When I run the app in iPhone with iOS 11.2.5 it shows following error message

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/80A98E72-4896-4D03-B2CF-5DEB9B9970CD/Map.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/80A98E72-4896-4D03-B2CF-5DEB9B9970CD/Map.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/80A98E72-4896-4D03-B2CF-5DEB9B9970CD/Map.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
```

I'm using Xcode 9.2, iOS 11.2, Swift 4.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution? Does it affect your app? (my app shows a blank map)